# Activation of network failed. constantly?

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, broadcom

Ever since I switched to Ubuntu from Windows on my old HP Pavilion Slimline, I've been experiencing unreliable network issues. Sometimes the computer just tends to disconnect from the network and this stops me from connecting to any other connections that are nearby. I know it isn't a router issue as it works for my other Ubuntu-powered laptop (HP Stream 14) and also on my win windows 10 Laptop. I've attempted to reinstall the network manager to no avail. There are many possibilities. I am aware that my computer is far from the router, so this may be an issue, though I doubt it is. I've also tried installing additional drivers, but there are none. It is a huge inconvenience as I have to constantly reboot the PC to get back online. Any commands I should run/any additional information I should provide?

**Results of iwconfig**

```
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlx701a0486ccb7  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"VM-guest9834714"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 3A:35:D1:CA:E1:71   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:179  Invalid misc:236   Missed beacon:0
```

**sudo lshw -C network results**

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 02
       serial: 90:e6:ba:ec:1d:d2
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:18 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:fdfff000-fdffffff memory:fdfe0000-fdfeffff memory:febe0000-febfffff
  *-usb:1
       description: Wireless interface
       product: 802.11 bg WLAN
       vendor: Ralink
       physical id: 8
       bus info: usb@1:8
       logical name: wlx701a0486ccb7
       version: 0.01
       serial: 70:1a:04:86:cc:b7
       capabilities: usb-2.00 ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt73usb driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic firmware=1.7 ip=192.168.1.4 link=yes maxpower=300mA multicast=yes speed=480Mbit/s wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Comment: Wireless or Wired connection problem? If wireless, at -80 dBm, I'd expect problems.

Comment: Wireless.. Is my hardware the problem? It is an old pc

Comment: You're too far away from your wireless router... and/or your older wireless adapter isn't up to the task... and/or you have an older router that isn't up to the task.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought it was just Ubuntu. I have a wifi connector. Would that be helpful?

Comment: What's "wifi connector"?

Comment: Nevermind it's useless in my case